# Is there a way int is converted to list using python

Tags: python, list, fibonacci

I have tried to add two numbers in the list. The result, generated was integer. I could like to use append function for list to add this integer to existing list. However, I am getting error the operation is not executable.

Fibo is a defined list

```py
Fibo_FV = Fibo[i] + Fibo[i+1] 

print(Fibo_FV)
##result is sum of two numbers in the list

Fibo_final = Fibo.append(Fibo_FV)

print(Fibo_final)
##Answer is none
```

I am not sure why I am seeing none in when printed `Fibo_final`. My expectation is it should be new list with Fibo and newly added value concatenated into it. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: _I am not sure why I am seeing none in when printed Fibo_final_ The `.append()` method does not return anything, therefore you get `None` by default.  `Fibo.append(Fibo_FV)` modifies the list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fibo_final = Fibo.append(Fibo_FV)
```

The function `list.append` modifies the list in place and returns None.
The same is true for many other built-in operations, `list.extend`, `dict.update`, `set.add`, etc..

You can just do

```
Fibo.append(Fibo_FV)
print(Fibo)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Do these two separately as below

```
Fibo.append(Fibo_FV)
Fibo_final = Fibo
print(Fibo_final)
```

Why this happened is because the append is a function and it does not return anything, so your Fibo_final contains None.